# Can't locate php.exe

Tags: web-platform-installer, webmatrix-2

I am new to web programming,
I have installed PHP for webmatrix. my php sites work perfectly but I need to use "php tools" in command line but it gives error "'php' is not recognized as an internal...." 
I know first, I should locate php.exe file but although I searched a lot, I could not find it.

Where does wps install it? or What should I do to use "php" command in command line.

Comment: You can perform a file search in your system so you can find it. What operating system are you on?

Comment: win7-64bit. I did it. No result :/

Comment: fool me. I found it. thx

Comment: Please post where you found it ... I didn't know that Microsoft provided a free PHP development platform ...

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I am really emberessed to say that: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3 (: